# Creating a dictionary from list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Right now I have a list of words and numbers:

`List = [("purple", 8), ("orange", 2),...]`

I want to make this into a dictionary:

`Dictionary = [{"word":" purple", "number":8}, ...]`

How do I go about this? Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Note that `Dictionary` is not a *dictionary*. It's a *list of dictionaries*.

Comment: are you sure what you want isn't {'purple':8,'orange':2} ?

Answer (score 4):

```
In [3]: [{'word': x, 'number': y} for x, y in List]
Out[3]: [{'word': 'purple', 'number': 8}, {'word': 'orange', 'number': 2}]
```

Though most probably you want this:

```
In [4]: dict(List)
Out[4]: {'orange': 2, 'purple': 8}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary = [{"word": word, "number": number} for word, number in List]
```